# hide left pane of datasheet view in subform

Tags: ms-access, view, datasheet

is it possible to hide the left pane of the datasheet view (marked red on the image below)?

[datasheet view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qitHZ.png)

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are called **Record Selectors** and you cannot remove / hide them in datasheet view. They are an integral part of it, as are the column headers.

You can disable them in a continuous form.

Comment: thanks for your answer. However, i already tried that- i changed the defaultView to continous and set the selectors to false... nothing changed. No error- just nothing---

Comment: The default view doesn't matter. In **Form View** you can disable them. In **Datasheet View** not.

Comment: The suggestion here is to create a continues form, or what is called a multiple-items form. It can look very much like a datasheet view, but it will not have record selectors (they can be turned off)